# Problems with class embedding in keras

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, word-embeddings

I am doing a toy example with mushroom dataset to learn class embedding with keras:

I am trying to embed a single feature:

```
inputs = Input(shape=[1])
emb = Embedding(input_dim=cap_shape_dummy.shape[1], output_dim=3)(inputs)
output = Dense(units=1,activation='sigmoid')(emb)
model = Model(inputs=inputs,outputs=output)
```

However I always receive the same error when I try to fit the model:

```
Error when checking target: expected dense_2 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (8124, 1)
```

Am I doing anything wrong? Did I miss anything with category embedding?
Thanks.

Comment: I think your problem can be solved by adding 'model.add(Flatten())' before the dense layer, or see the answer of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48674881/keras-expected-3-dimensions-but-got-array-with-shape-dense-model

Comment: Why would I need to Flatten? the output fronm my embedding is not multi dim? Would you please explain me what each param mean? because maybe is not clear

Answer (score -1):

```
inputs = Input(shape=[1])
emb = Embedding(input_dim=cap_shape_dummy.shape[1], output_dim=3)(inputs)
flat = Flatten()(emb)
output = Dense(units=1,activation='sigmoid')(flat)
model = Model(inputs=inputs,outputs=output)
```

Comment: Please format your code as code, and add some explanation behind it.